# Expand __COUNTER__ macro once per source file

Tags: c, xcode4, llvm, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a macro that will expand the `__COUNTER__` macro only once per source file. I understand fully how macros work with their expansion but I'm having difficulty with this one. I want to expand the `__COUNTER__` macro once at the top of the file and then each reference to that define will not expand the `__COUNTER__` to it's next number.

So I want to fully expand `__COUNTER__` into a single value and then use that one value consistently through the current working source file.

I can only use features that are available to **C**.

Comment: Template metaprogramming, you can "generate" IDs running code at...compile time.

Comment: I am limited to using only C so this solution must be on the preprocessor

Comment: Does the value need to be available at compile time? Or can it wait until runtime?

Comment: Must be compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The `__COUNTER__` extension (I suppose you are using a compiler from the gcc family) is too restricted for such a use. The difficulty is that if you put it into another macro, say `TOTO`, it is not expanded at definition but only at its use. So each invocation of `TOTO` will give rise to a new value of the counter.

In [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/p99__id_8h.html) I have a portable replacement for this, that achieves that goal with some `#include` hackery. `P99_FILEID` is then an per file identifier, and `P99_LINEID` an ID that should be unique for all lines in your compilation unit (but use with care).

Another alternative if you just need a compile time constant and nothing in the preprocessor itself would be to use the counter in an enumeration constant.

```
enum { toto_id = __COUNT__, };
```

Comment: This looks very much like what I need, where I can download your P99 and where can I see it's license?

Comment: @FelixJones, all that you find via the main page p99.gforge.inria.fr. The license is QPL, but will hopefully change to GPL, soon.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, every file has the number 1111.

I am guessing this is because the macro is not kept between source inputs, I will have to see if I can set it as a global define for my compiler

Comment: The documentation says "An id that identifies different times of inclusion of the file "p99_id.h" so you'd have to include that file in  every header and .c file to get the counter updated.

Comment: Ah, not going to happen I'm afraid.

I'll just have to cope with having an error-prone section in my software